# Jsoup extract dates from google search

Tags: java, date, jsoup, google-query-language

Through jsoup I google query for certain requests and save the output urls. I want also for each url I find to save the date created(or modified) how can I do that? My code is derived from http://www.mkyong.com/java/jsoup-send-search-query-to-google/
.

Will I have to enter each url in order to extract the date modified?

**Edit :**
I fetch a date created-modified of a webpage like this :

```
Connection.Response con= Jsoup.connect("http://www.example.ex")
    .userAgent("Mozilla")
    .ignoreContentType(true)
    .timeout(5000)
    .execute();
System.out.println("Date= " + con.header("Last-Modified"));
```

So how can I find multiple date-created of websites from a google-query using jsoup without traversing each finding url.

Comment: Can you show an example for a query that has the "date created"?